# get all currency filter items in an Angular view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, currency

I'm currently working in a logic that should change all prices in a view according to the user selected currency (dls, eur, brl), I was wondering about if it is possible to get all the elements in a view in where the "currency" filter get's applied. e.g.

```
<div>
    {{ somePrice | currency }}
    {{ anotherPrice | currency }}
    {{ vacationTicketCost | currency }}
</div>
```

and in the controller do some magic that ends up with an array like

```
var pricesArray = [somePrice, anotherPrice, vacationTicketCost];
```

so that in that way I would be able to apply the currency change to all the values. Is that possible or should I look for another approach ?

Regards.

Comment: You should look into `$rootScope` to store your current currency. From which you can access in your filter.

Comment: @JosueIbarra mmm... I don't think that's a good idea, have in mind that there are gonna be many values,  so ... I don't think $rootScope it's a good approach

Comment: I think you should possibly clarify exactly what the end result is that you want. Explain why you are wanting to get an array of the filtered prices, because while what you are asking might be possible there is almost definitely a better way to do it.

Comment: I mean, keep the display logic of the currency in the filter. You only need one global variable with the current currency to change it in the whole application.

Comment: @JosueIbarra oh! I see, maybe that could work, could you provide a minimal example ?

Comment: Sure, im on mobile so i cant code right now. When i get back on my pc.

Comment: The answer I added is similar to his suggestion. Instead of putting it on the $rootScope I am using a "value" service but using the $rootScope wouldn't be that much different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your asking is probably not a great idea because it requires your controller to know about your view. Instead what you want to do is pass the `currency` filter into your controller and use it from there to create your display values. Then you can have them in your controller as well.

```
angular.module("app", [])
    .value("currentCurrency", "eur")
    .controller("controller", function(currentCurrency, currencyFilter){
        var vm = this;
        vm.val = "1.25";
        vm.currentCurrency = currentCurrency;

        vm.displayValue = currencyFilter(vm.val, vm.currentCurrency);
    });
```

Angular allows you to pass in filters by adding a parameter called `filternameFilter` into the constructor function of your controller.

Here is a codepen showing the above: http://codepen.io/troylelandshields/pen/EKjwRy

Comment: @flaalf If this solution works for you, you should mark it as the answer.